# Mongoose findEach?

Tags: mongoose

I realize I quite often need to write:

```
Model.find({criteria: 'foo'})
  .then(models => models.map(model => processModel(model)));
```

I feel there should be some kind of `Model.findEach` like in [rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each) which would allow the following:

```
Model.findEach({criteria: 'foo'})
  .then(model => processModel(model));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it:

```
module.exports = (schema, options) => {
  schema.statics.findEach = function(criteria, applyFn) {
    return this.find(criteria)
      .then(results => Promise.all(results.map(applyFn)))
  }
};
```

Used like so:

```
mongoose.plugin(require('../lib/mongoose-find-each'));
```

Works like a charm :)